# How do I know the version of LLVM on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, llvm

I has installed the LLVM by invoking`sudo apt-get install LLVM`, but I have no idea to check the version of llvm.
And unfortunately, I figured out the the target version of LLVM I needed if 2.6. How can I check the version of current LLVM and install the correct LLVM?
On ubuntu14.04 LTS

Comment: try llc --version

Comment: Another useful program is llvm-config. try llvm-config --version